# Rails form use text field for object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a DiscountCode model with a code attribute (string). My Booking model belongs_to :discount_code. In the Booking form, I don't want to put a dropdown to select a DiscountCode, I just want a string field (using SimpleForm):

```
f.input :discount_code
```

where the user can type eg "XMAS2015". I turn the string in a DiscountCode object in the controller:

```
new_params[:discount_code] = DiscountCode.find_by code: params[:booking][:discount_code]
```

... and I use new_params to build my Booking. If there are no errors, all goes well, but if there are and the form is shown again, the string field is filled with the object instead of the code:

```
#<DiscountCode:0x0000000baf2d68>
```

I cannot turn it back like this:

```
@booking.discount_code = @booking.discount_code.code
```

because @booking.discount_code should be a DiscountCode and not a string.

Is there any solution to change the object back to a string in the form, or should I use another field name like discount_code_text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply set it to text and add the proper `input_html` value:

```
= f.input :discount_code, as: :text, input_html: { value: '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use discount_code field in the booking table as there is a `has_one` relationship and only a single attribute as a code.

The way you are doing currently is only applicable when you have more attributes in the context of booking_code.